# opening a new Form when clicking an pictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I need to open a new form in WinForm when the user's clicking on the pictureBox (to get redirected to the information "window").

[image: this is the pictureBox]

Anyway, have no idea how to pull this off... So any answers/ideas will be appreciated a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the eventhandler of your picturebox, search the click event and double click on it.
You will now get an event like this:

```
private void picturebox_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The next step is to add your code to it.

```
private void picturebox_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourFormName yourForm = new YourFormName ();
    yourForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

And voila, you're done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to the PictureBox Clicked event and open your Form there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, as well under your void:

```
new FormNameHere().Show();
```